# What multi-platform language handles serial connections well?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, cross-platform

I need to create a simple application that is multi-platform that will send data over serial connections without much fuss for me or end users. The sole purpose is to be able to read and write tables of data to an Arduino over a USB interface (that presents itself as a serial interface).

I have some experience with python, perl, and php for what it's worth.

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: I'd go with whatever language has bindings for the library you most probably will need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Languages you noted are all interpreted you need an Interpreter on the Platforms. If you don't dare installing a pee-family interpreter on a windows machine which is the most difficult platform i think then you can use it.

If you want real multi-platform you should consider using a compiled Language like C, which you compile for the different versions, or use Java and run it on top of the JRE which is available on most platforms.

Comment: Java does not have serial support in the default runtime library.

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn, a quick search revealed that: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html I think it would be a "failure to communicate" if it wouldn't be possible with Java.

Comment: It is not part of the standard library.